# Is it possible to use PHPMailer without TURNING OFF 2-Step Verification?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, phpmailer, host

I succeeded in sending a mail using PHPMailer, but I had to TURN OFF 2-Step Verification (google account in my case).

Is it possible to use PHPMailer without TURNING OFF 2-Step Verification?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to go through that mess with PHPMailer's XOAUTH2 installation. Sign into your Google Account, then go to "Sign-in & security" > "App Passwords". There you generate a unique token for your app (name app however you want) and use that token instead of password. All other (smtp) settings remain the same.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using XOAUTH2 authentication. This will require your second factor to get a token during initial setup, but should then operate repeatedly without asking again. This also means you don't need to enable the "allow less secure apps" setting. See [the PHPMailer docs on Gmail with XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) and [the Gmail XOAUTH2 example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps). It's easier if you use the as-yet unreleased [version 6.0 branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0). There's really too much code involved to include it all here meaningfully.